# Prevent WHERE from matching on same row

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables, `ships` and `officers`. A `ship` has multiple `officers`. To search for a `ship` with a specific `officer`, I have a query like this:

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM ships AS a 
LEFT JOIN bridge_officers AS aBoff ON a.id = aBoff.ship_id  
WHERE aBoff.profession = :aprofession
GROUP BY a.id
```

This will result in all `ships` with an `officer` that has `:aprofession`. The same `JOIN`/`WHERE` is repeated to filter by more than one `officer`.

For example:

```sql
SELECT a.id
FROM ships AS a 
LEFT JOIN bridge_officers AS aBoff ON a.id = aBoff.ship_id
LEFT JOIN bridge_officers AS bBoff ON a.id = bBoff.ship_id
WHERE  aBoff.profession = :aprofession AND  bBoff.rank = :brank
GROUP BY a.id
```

This will result in all `ships` with that has an `:aprofession` and `:brank` `officers`. My desired behavior is that only ships with two different `officers` matching these criteria are returned. If a single `officer` has both `:aproffesion` and `:brank`, it'll return that ship. I'd prefer if each `WHERE` condition would only match to one join.

Is there anyway to accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: if I understood you correctly, you want to keep the same conditions in where clause. But Why left Join? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp . read this. will help you to play out with joins. My assumption is you need inner join or full outer join. play with them.  if it doesn't help, reach out here again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another condition to the second JOIN that it be a different officer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM ships AS a 
LEFT JOIN bridge_officers AS aBoff ON a.id = aBoff.ship_id
LEFT JOIN bridge_officers AS bBoff ON a.id = bBoff.ship_id AND aBoff.id != bBoff.id
WHERE  aBoff.profession = :aprofession AND  bBoff.rank = :brank
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to the join condition to prevent same-row matches:

```
LEFT JOIN bridge_officers AS bBoff ON a.id = bBoff.ship_id
    AND aBoff.id < bBoff.id
```

chosing `<` rather than `!=` to halve the intermediate result set; only producing unique combinations of any two officers.

Also, there seems to be a bug in the `where` clause - your question states *a single officer has both :aproffesion and :brank*, but your `where` clause

```
WHERE aBoff.profession = :aprofession
AND bBoff.rank = :brank
```

checks if the officer as a certain profession and the *other* officer has a certain rank - it seems the conditions should be applied to the same joined table `aBoff`:

```
WHERE aBoff.profession = :aprofession
AND aBoff.rank = :brank -- aBoff.rank, not bBoff.rank
```

There's also another subtle issue with your query: by applying a `where` clause to your outer joined tables you convert them to *inner* joins, because the joined row must exist (and be joined to) for the `where` clause to be true, so the `LEFT` keyword is meaningless here and should be removed for clarity:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id
FROM ships AS a
JOIN bridge_officers AS aBoff ON a.id = aBoff.ship_id
JOIN bridge_officers AS bBoff ON a.id = bBoff.ship_id
  AND aBoff.id < bBoff.id
WHERE aBoff.profession = :aprofession
AND aBoff.rank = :brank
```